# How to force Google+ Instant Upload to perform an upload right away?

Tags: google-plus, instant-upload

Sometimes I want to share photos my friend right after after we take the shots. I want those photos to appear in my Google+ Instant Upload album immediately, rather than waiting for it automatically do it.

How can I force "instant upload" to run?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your settings aren't preventing the upload somehow? E.g. make sure that it's set to upload over both Wi-Fi and mobile data.

Comment: You could always share them manually.

Comment: Where to check for the setting? In Gallery app? I cannot find that configuration.

Comment: I would like to share photo manually by using the photo links rather than sending the photo file. So I need photos be online via Instant Upload

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Google+ app, select `Settings -> Instant Upload` and press the `Upload all` item, it will *just* upload any photos that haven't already been uploaded.

As noted in the comments, you can also `share` individual photos in your album via Google+.

Comment: I prefer to share link to the photo rather than transfer the photo. So I need it goes online to Goolge+ via Instant Upload.

Comment: I cannot see Instant Upload in Setting.

Comment: Answer clarified to indicate which settings.

Answer (score 7):

1. Open the *Photos* application on Android.  It can be found in the Main application list.
2. The three dots in the upper right corner -> *Settings*
3. Choose *Auto Backup*.
4. Under Auto backup, under the third section *Backup Settings* choose *Back up all*.

Make sure that your connection settings permit you the backup - you must be using a WiFi connection if under *Back up Photos* you have chosen *Wifi only* and you must be charging if you've put at tick next to *While charging only*.

The same procedure could be done through the *Google+* app instead of the *Photos* app.

Comment: For me it always shows backup successful but no photos are uploaded

Comment: On my phone, _Settings_ is under the menu that slides in from the left after I tap the three lines menu in the upper left-hand corner. I guess it's been updated since this answer was added.

Answer (score 1):

go to `Settings/Accounts & Sync/Google/`*(choose Google Account if necessary)*`/`

Google Plus Photos is probably already checked. Un-check it and re-check it. This will force it to re-sync immediately.

Someone should develop a button to do all this automatically. I edit all my photos in Google Plus before posting on Etsy.com. I force the sync so I can work continuously.

HTC One S running Android 4.1.1